# New Column with average by Date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I have this table:

```
OrganizationCode | CreatedDate              | TotalCost
102              |  2015-05-18 00:00:00.000 | 200
102              |  2015-05-18 00:00:00.000 | 550
102              |  2015-05-15 00:00:00.000 | 700
102              |  2015-05-15 00:00:00.000 | 1200
103              |  2015-01-27 00:01:12.720 | 1275,46
103              |  2015-01-27 00:01:12.720 | 1275,46 
103              |  2015-01-27 00:01:12.720 | 1275,46
```

And i need add two column:

Daily Average = Sum of the values by date

Daily Amount = Amount by Date

I want the result below:

```
OrganizationCode | CreatedDate      | TotalCost | Daily Average | Daily Amount    
-----------------|------------------|-----------|---------------|--------    
102              | 2015-05-18 00:00 | 200       | 375           |  2    
102              | 2015-05-18 00:00 | 550       | 375           |  2    
102              | 2015-05-15 00:00 | 700       | 950           |  2    
102              | 2015-05-15 00:00 | 1200      | 950           |  2    
103              | 2015-01-27 00:01 | 1275,46   | 1275,46       |  3    
103              | 2015-01-27 00:01 | 1275,46   | 1275,46       |  3    
103              | 2015-01-27 00:01 | 1275,46   | 1275,46       |  3
```

I try this query:

```
   SELECT OrganizationCode 
          , CreatedDate 
          , (SELECT avg(TotalCost) AS x
                 FROM #TempLocalOrg
                 Group By CAST(CreatedDate as date)) 
   FROM #TempLocalOrg
```

No sucess, the sub select works, but I need to duplicate results

Comment: You have tried something, right? What’s the problem? Share your SQL query with us.

Comment: It seems the values for Daily Average and Daily Amount comes from a temp table #TempLocalOrg. Could you add this table schema to the question too?

Comment: Sorry, my first post. It includes query.
It is a temporary table, but in this case can be considered as normal table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use window functions:

```
SELECT OrganizationCode, CreatedDate
     , AVG(TotalCost) OVER ( PARTITION BY CreatedDate ) AS [Daily Average]
     , COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY CreatedDate ) AS [Daily Amount]
  FROM #TempLocalOrg;
```

The above assumes that dates are rounded or truncated to the nearest day.

Comment: And if they're not already truncated to the date level, you can do `partition by cast(createddate as date)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OrganizationCode 
      , CreatedDate 
      , TotalCost
      , aggregates.AvgCost AS 'Daily Average '
      , aggregates.CountCost AS 'Daily Amount'
FROM #TempLocalOrg tmp
CROSS APPLY
(
   SELECT AVG(TotalCost) as AvgCost
         ,COUNT(1) AS CountCost
   FROM #TempLocalOrg crossTemp
   WHERE CAST(tmp.CreatedDate as date) = CAST(crossTemp.CreatedDate as date)
) aggregates
```

As you needed not to aggregate the values, we couldn't use group by. 
Instead, I used a CROSS APPLY to match every line's Date and aggregate it's results, as to apply it to every line distinct line.
Feel free to contact me if you need any clarification on anything.